# How to encapsulate an external flutter package within my flutter package, so that the users do not have to install the external package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-packages

I am creating a flutter package. My flutter package contains a function that uses another external flutter package called 'crypto'. But the users of my flutter package do not want to use or install the crypto. So are there anyway to encapsulate the crypto inside my flutter package without asking the users to install it in order to use that functions in my package?

Answer (score 0):

You could export the crypto package from your own package.
This is what packages such as [freezed_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed_annotation) are doing for [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection), [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation) and [meta](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) packages.

```dart
// ...

export 'package:collection/collection.dart' show DeepCollectionEquality;
export 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
export 'package:meta/meta.dart';

// ...
```

[source](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/blob/master/packages/freezed_annotation/lib/freezed_annotation.dart#L4-L6)

Comment: Thankyou. Should this be done on the same place where i am importing the crypto library for my code?

Comment: It should be done in a file that is exposed from your package. You don't have to put it in the same place you are doing a crypto import.

Comment: Therefore according to this way users do not have to install crypto package in order to run my package?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to import your package to have access to crypto.